# Name of a component

Tags: potentiometer

As part of a DIY flight sim panel building, I would like to use what I could best describe as a "one axis joystick" or maybe a "slide potentiometer with center detent that would go back to the center after the user interaction".

Those two description fit what I'm looking for (I don't care if it's a joystick or a slider) but the crucial part is that it would output some analog value around the center value AND auto reset to the center once the user is done wih it.

This question might seem dumb to you but I can't find a good enough way to describe it that ebay brings back some answers to me.

Hope someone can help, have a great day =)

PS : As a last resort (french pun intended) I will Mc Guyver my way out of it with a regular potentiometer and two springs.

Comment: I think just searching for "single axis joystick" might get what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Single axis, return to center, joystick* should do it for you.

I love your pun.

Answer (score 1):

Single-axis joystick or "two direction" joystick. Return to center/centre or "spring to center/centre"

[Here](http://www.controldevices.net/P&G/PennyAndGilesPDF/JC1500-tech-data-Ver-6-08_12-pdf%20(2).pdf) are some high-end ones that use contactless technology rather than pots.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely find that a joystick that relies on a mechanical means to return to a center position will not reliably leave the pot or other transducer with the same output value each time upon release.

You may wish to consider adding capacitive touch sensing to the joystick handle. This would allow for positive confirmation of release and a forced logical zeroing of the transducer.